# Authentication for non User-based entities

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

In my application I've two models that can make requests to the backend. One is `django.contrib.auth.models.User` based to is use `rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication` and the second one is an entity named `Hub`.

I use `Authorization: HubToken <TOKEN>` for authenticating Hubs requests but handle it manually in every single endpoint. I mean I need to check if request comes from `User` or from `Hub` and take some further steps.

I know I can implement a [custom authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#custom-authentication) but it's all User-based. How can I make a custom authentication for `Hub`?

Comment: Can you instead create different user types `User` and `Hub` and then check for authentication schema based on that. Then maybe use a proxy model `Hub` for convenience. Does that make sense?

Comment: @mariodev, that's what I did, however I don't like it very much :/